# One-to-Many Shortest Path query support in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

Does neo4j have support for one-to-many shortest path queries?
An example of such query would be: Given a node i, and a list of several other nodes N, compute the shortest paths from i to all the nodes that belong to N.

I am aware of this thread: [Neo4j shortest path (BFS) distances query variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162735/neo4j-shortest-path-bfs-distances-query-variants), but it is specifically for one-to-all queries. 
My question is for one-to-many queries.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get All paths from one node to multiple nodes

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((s:skill)-[r]->(s1:skill))
WHERE id(s) = 123
AND id(s1) IN [1,2,3]

RETURN p
```

This is the one way to get paths between one-to-many.
I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Probably also fix `s` to a single node. Otherwise you get shortest paths to all nodes in the graph.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks, I have updated query to fix s.