# One-to-Many Shortest Path query limitations in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

Running one-to-many shortest path queries on a Neo4j database as per the cypher query format described in this thread: [One-to-Many Shortest Path query support in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377196/one-to-many-shortest-path-query-support-in-neo4j), appears to have some limitations for the list of the target nodes, (ie. running a query on a graph with 500K nodes and 1M edges seems to not be able to handle a query with >1000 to-many targets).

Is there any official document from Neo4j to address the issue of limitations to the number of nodes that Neo4j supports for the case of this kind of queries (or any other queries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard and fast rule as it can vary depending on your hardware and your configuration.  The more memory that you throw at it, the better it performs.  See this guide for information about tuning Neo4j:

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/